# Storage_path returning path without slashes in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to get the path to the Storage funtion in laravel and read it in javascript,

The way I try to do this is :

```
var storagePath="<?php echo storage_path(); ?>";
console.log('StoragePath ',storagePath);
```

But this logs out a path like this :

```
StoragePath  C:wampwwwd3projectFirststorage
```

I do need the slashes but seems like 'storage_page()'  trims them , not sure if this is a security thing,can I still read  the path to the  folder using the string above or get the slashes untrimmed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because javascript thinks you want to escape something. So all you have to do, is escape the backslashes. [addslashes](http://php.net/addslashes) will do the trick:

```
var storagePath = "<?php echo addslashes(storage_path()); ?>";
console.log('StoragePath ',storagePath);
```

Comment: So its java script that trims the slashes not storage_path()?

Comment: Yes and no. Its because backslash is used to escape certain symbols (like single and double quotes in string, etc). In order to 'print' a backslash, it needs to be escaped too, otherwise it would try to escape the following character (which leads to an javascript error `SyntaxError: malformed hexadecimal character escape sequence`)